# Will there be sex in Heaven (the new Earth)?

Tags: heaven, sexuality

I have heard many people ask and now I have been considering the question myself. Will there be sex on the new Earth? What is the reasoning for either position?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [1](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/22944/why-is-there-no-marriage-in-heaven) [2](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/20060/can-humans-fall-in-love-with-each-other-in-heaven) [3](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/11549/do-we-retain-our-gender-in-heaven) [4](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1570/what-happens-to-marriage-on-the-new-earth) [5](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5024/will-there-be-new-people-or-reproduction-in-heaven-or-the-next-life).

Comment: Maybe five is a duplicate, but there is still the difference between sex and procreation. Perhaps there will be a different mechanism in the Kingdom. These are all very closely related, however, I would not call any of them duplicates. But if I were forced I would say number 5.

Comment: Many issues related to this topic have already been dealt with on this site. Perhaps if you can review them and then [edit] this question to focus only on whatever detail remains outstanding for you (and show some of your research leading up to the question we could reopen this.

Comment: There won't be sex in heaven because people will no longer marry. It appears that it is likely there will be no further reproduction, as the number of people will have accumulated to what it should be.

Answer (score 1):

There is very little Biblical evidence to suggest that there will be no sex on the new Earth nor in Heaven after Christ's second coming.

The idea spawns from an inferred interpretation of [Mark 12:25](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%2012&version=NIV)

> When the dead rise, they will neither marry nor be given in marriage; they will be like the angels in heaven.

The background story is that the Pharisees are attempting to trap Jesus and pose the question of who a woman would be married to after the resurrection if she has been widowed seven times. Jesus replies that she will be married to none of them.

What Jesus did not say is that there will be no sex or no procreation.

This idea is very old and comes from a time when it was unthinkable sin to copulate outside of marriage. Sex and marriage were so intertwined at times in some Christian cultures (Puritan) that they were equated. Some thought, and I am sure that some actually still do, that because there is no marriage then there surely is no sex either.

Without this verse, the Bible is silent on this issue.

Today, I do not know of a single denomination that teaches that there will be no sex after the Resurrection, though I would not be surprise if there are a few small groups, and I reserve the right to be corrected.

Another inference about this scripture is that there will be no gender in Heaven. That is clearly related, but takes the idea to the next level. I discuss this in [the answer to a different question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/14255/3961).

Comment: Here are three related questions: [Why is there no marriage in Heaven?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/22944/3961) - [Can humans fall in love with each other in heaven?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/20060/3961) - [Does the act of sex constitute marriage in God's eyes?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/6724/3961)

Comment: This would be true if Revelation 21:27 didn't apply to New Heaven and New Earth. If sin is not possible there and if most denominations are true to consider any extramarital sex as a sin, there will be no sex. I would discuss this in detail, but it's too late to send an answer.

Comment: @Pavel That is a logical step, however, still inferred from the Scripture, not explicitly stated.

Comment: Yes, but this shift from "we don't know anything" to "it's not directly written, but this logically follows what is written" is enough for many denominations to teach this. This question didn't get to creeds and other important articles of faith not because it wasn't believed, but because it is considered unimportant. Catholic position on this was stated somewhere in John Paul II's Theology of body, but I don't want to spend hours searching for exact citations when the comments won't let me to cite it completely.

Comment: @fredsbend "it _was_ unthinkable sin to copulate outside of marriage"? Sex still is sin outside marriage (1 Corinthians 7:36, Proverbs 5, every mention of "fornication").

Comment: @LeeSleek Yes, but I mean just the general population, not only the righteous believers.

Comment: Sex out side of marriage is unthinkable sin but on the new earth we will all be married in christ, one husband which is christ and one bride which is the church and body of christ, so there will be no more marriage because all will already be married.